# Lync Enterprise deployment file share

Tags: lync

What is the file share used for in a Lync Enterprise deployment?

Can I create the share on one of my front end pool servers or does it need to be on a completely different server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lync File Share is used to house a bunch of Lync Shared Resources between servers.
Once up in running the server generates 3 subfolders:

1-ApplicationServer-1 - This is where custom application services settings are stored. like custom music on hold (I think).

1-CentralMgmt-1 - This is the Central Management store replication service does is magic in replicating changes to all the servers in your topology.

1-Webservices-1 - This the web services store which contains among other things Device logs (Lync/OCS phones logs), Device Update logs, Meeting stuff etc.

Also if you have and Archive server, it is where some archive data goes as well.

You define the Share during setup in the Topology Builder.

And yes you can definitely co-locate the share in a standard edition server deployment, but you have to separate it out if you are doing an enterprise pool.

Remember that you only have to create the share, Lync server will create the rest of the folders during first time setup and will set its own permissions.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms.lync.tbdep.addfrontendfilestorepage.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsplanningdeployment/thread/10a9fa65-be6e-4ece-a46c-3d038d0acfee